# Mass Remove IP Subnet?

Tags: centos, ip

How do I mass delete IPs I no longer use on the server (secondary assignment, not prime subnet)

For example I have a specific /27 I want to remove in one shot, instead of one IP at a time via whm delete IPs function

I'm using Cpanel/WHM with Centos 5x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just edit /etc/ips and rebuild the IP address pool in WHM after you are done.

A simple operation might be:

```
cat /etc/ips | sed '/^192.168.2/d' > /etc/ips.new
```

.. verify it

```
mv /etc/ips.new /etc/ips
```

Not sure on what you have in there in the neighborhood of the subnet you want to remove, so you will probably want to make the regex a bit more precise :)